# Control animation of getWindow().setLayout() (using Window's TransitionManager)

Tags: android, android-transitions, android-windowmanager

I have an activity with `isWindowFloating` set to true. It can switch from being fullscreen to popup at any time. I use this code to toggle the state.

```
getWindow().setLayout(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT); //popup
getWindow().setLayout(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT); //fullscreen
```

The window resizes with a nice animation if I use absolute values or `WRAP_CONTENT`, e.g. `getWindow().setLayout(1000, 1000);`, **but when I use `MATCH_PARENT` there is no animation**.

It has something to do with the Window's Transition Manager, because when I use `getWindow().setTransitionManager(null)` all the animations disappear entirely. But I have no idea how to write a new `TransitionManager` for such a situation. No useful resources on that. Any ideas to push me in the right direction?